# Web Scraping of crunchbase data using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

**Code:**

```
import requests

response= requests.get("https://www.crunchbase.com/search/people/field/organizations/num_employees_enum/anheuser-busch")

response.raise_for_status()

webFile =open('myFile.txt', 'wb')

for chunk in res.iter_content(10000):
    webFile.write(chunk)
    webFile.close()
```

I found the following error:

> requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 416 Client Error: Requested Range Not
>   Satisfiable for url:
>   https://www.crunchbase.com/search/people/field/organizations/num_employees_enum/anheuser-busch

Comment: Don't know if this will fix your immediate problem, but change:.    res.iter_content     to     response.iter_content

Comment: Still Error is same

Answer (score 6):

If you remove the line `response.raise_for_status()` you will receive the following output from crunchbase:

## Pardon Our Interruption...

As you were browsing **www.crunchbase.com** something about your browser made us think you were a bot. There are a few reasons this might happen:

- You're a power user moving through this website with super-human speed.
- You've disabled JavaScript in your web browser.
- A third-party browser plugin, such as Ghostery or  NoScript, is preventing JavaScript from running. Additional information is available in this support article.

In fact, you are a bot, instead of Python requests you should try using their own API.

**EDIT**

To use the crunchbase API, you need to register here: https://about.crunchbase.com/solutions/ the free basic access licence should be enough to access organizations according the documentation.

Once you have registered you will have a user API key, then you can make your requests as follows:

[https://api.crunchbase.com/v3.1/organizations?user_key=[user_key]](https://api.crunchbase.com/v3.1/organizations?user_key=%5Buser_key%5D)

The equivalent to the query you made using the API would be something like this:

```
import json,requests

url = "https://api.crunchbase.com/v3.1/organizations/anheuser-busch"

params = dict(user_key="your_key")

resp = requests.get(url=url, params=params)
data = json.loads(resp.text)

webFile = open('myFile.txt', 'w')

for organization in data:
    webFile.write(organization["num_employees_max"])

webFile.close()
```

Haven't tested it myself but it should get you going.

Here is all the data available for organizations: https://data.crunchbase.com/docs/organization

And here is the reference to get started with the API: https://data.crunchbase.com/docs/using-the-api

Comment: import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


url= 'https://www.crunchbase.com/search/people/field/organizations/num_employees_enum/infosys'


response = requests.get(url)
html =response.content

soup=BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for div in soup.find_all("div", class_="grid-cell layout-row layout-align-start-center row-10 col-5"):
 print(div.text)

This is also not working

Comment: Why don't you use the API?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example, couldn't test it as I don't have a key right now but I hope it helps.

Comment: No I also have not key,

Comment: API access appears to be restricted to Enterprise accounts: https://about.crunchbase.com/products/pricing/

I guess this has changed since you last checked?